# Git pre-receive hook in python to check author time

Tags: python, git

I wrote a pre-receive hook in python to make sure the author date is not later than server date, here is the code:

```
import datetime, sys, subprocess

def validate_author_date(commit):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['git show --pretty=format:"%at"', commit],
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    x = p.stdout.readline()
    if x.strip():
        ad = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(x))
        return ad <= datetime.date.today()
    else:
        return False

for line in sys.stdin:
    (base, commit, ref) = line.strip().split()
    if not validate_author_date(commit):
        sys.exit('Date error: commit date is later than sys date. commit hash is %s' % commit)
```

Here is the problem: assume the server time is 2015-3-23, I push a commit with date 2015-3-25, and the hook does not work as expect.

---

Edit:some background information, there are many timers in our program, my colleagues change their system time for debug purpose, and forget to change the time when they commit the changes. I just want to write a hook to detect this situation and reject commits with future time.

Comment: It's always nice to hear what exactly does not work.
Btw. `String.strip()` is not an in-place modification you have to write `x = x.strip()` to get rid of the linefeed and additional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about what you expect and what you observe; but I think I know what the problem is anyway.

Take a look at the following:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
tree afd02e8830a8d41398d0d77983ae7783e0382b39
parent 46d403f13e5cb6d2b6bee6f942a679ea8978b9fa
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1426883513 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1426884806 -0700

Post 2.3 cycle (batch #11)

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

Note that the author and committer dates both have this extra `-0700` on the end.  Now:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%ad HEAD
Fri Mar 20 13:31:53 2015 -0700
$ git log -1 --pretty=format:%at HEAD
1426883513
$ git log -1 --date=raw --pretty=format:%ad HEAD
1426883513 -0700
$
```

If you just use `%at`, you get the raw time *without* the `-0700` time zone addition.  Use `--date=raw --pretty=format:%ad` to get both, and then apply the offset (which, note, is an hours-and-minutes offset, so for those odd 3-hours-and-30-minutes time zones you'll get something like `-0330`).

(I'd also recommend avoiding `shell=True` here, it just makes your `git log` or `git show` commands more complicated than if you simply break them up into argv words yourself:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '-1',
    '--date=raw', '--pretty=format:%ad', commit],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

for instance.)